# i can't understand parseInt method in this code

Tags: javascript, parseint

code is like that :)

```js
function test3(num) {
  if (num <= 9) {
    return num;
  }
  let rest = 1;
  while (num) {
    rest = rest * (num % 10);
    num = parseInt(num / 10);
  }
  if (rest <= 9) {
    return rest;
  }
  return test3(rest);
}
debugger;
let output = test3(786);
console.log(output); // --> 0
```

i understand other logic but, i dont understand 'parseInt'
how to work parseInt logic ?
apparently i m already read mdn, and any stackover flow answer, can't understand well..

Comment: Tip: `parseInt(n, 10)` to ensure it's always base 10.

Comment: What is this thing supposed to do? `test3` is not a very self-explanatory name.

Comment: @tadman That's the default, the explicit base hasn't been needed for years.

Comment: `parseInt()` is being used to remove the fraction after dividing.

Comment: @Barmar It still auto-converts stuff like `'0x600'` which some people would expect to be `0`.

Comment: @Barmar mdn disagrees with you.

Comment: Right. It's the default unless you specifically provide a hex prefix.

Comment: @Barmar what about `'071'` - thats octal, hence it being critical to specify it.

Comment: @DanielA.White That was true in some ES3 implementations, it was never in the spec, and ES5 prohibits it.

Comment: Anyway, since this code is parsing the result of an arithmetic operation, not a user-input string, it can never begin with any of those prefixes, so we don't have to worry about the base.

Comment: @Barmar i m already remove parseInt fraction,, but i dont understand clearly.. just sense.. i wanna more crystal clear.

Comment: If you replace parseInt with Math.floor it might make the code easier to understand.

Comment: `parseInt(num / 10)` is arguably incorrect here with or without the `, 10` – it should be `Math.floor(num / 10)`, and you might find it easier to understand the logic behind it after that change too? [`Math.floor` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)

Comment: @Pascal ohhh thank you soo much.. i will right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseInt()` is being used here to convert a number that may have a fraction after the decimal point into the integer part.

It works because if the argument to `parseInt()` isn't a string, it's first converted to a string, and then it parses an integer prefix from that. So `parseInt(3.14)` is equivalent to `parseInt('3.14')`, which returns `3`.

It's equivalent to `Math.floor()` in this context.